# Use CUIAutomation8 interface to detect metro style app

Tags: user-interface, visual-c++, com, automation

How I can use CoCreateInstance COM API to create a instance of CUIAutomation8 to detect windows 8, 8.1 metro style application.

I am using it in VS2010 under Windows 8.1 but getting error "'CUIAutomation8' : undeclared identifier"

Code,

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <shobjidl.h>
#include <objbase.h>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ole2.h>
#include <uiautomation.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <comutil.h>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <iostream>

IUIAutomation *_automation;


int main( void )
{
    HRESULT hrResult = S_OK;
    hrResult = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(CUIAutomation8), NULL,
                                CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&_automation));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I believe VS2010 came out before Windows 8. What is the value of Platform Toolset in project properties? Have you installed a newer Windows SDK?

Comment: Platform toolset is set to version v100. I never installed newer windows SDK? Do I need to install any thing?

Comment: I think you can either install VS2013 or install the free Windows SDK. If you do the latter, don’t know how to point the old Visual Studio at the new SDK though.

Comment: Ok. I will search for any Windows SDK on top of VS2010 that will resolve my issue. Is it possible without installing VS2013?

Comment: Here’s an article I found by googling: [how to use the Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8 within your Visual Studio 2010 projects](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/03/25/10287354.aspx). I have not tried it though.

Comment: Thanks yonran for your reply..I will try this and will update you!